# Validation Rule on an object with a status condition

Tags: validation, validation-rule

We currently have a validation rule setup stating that if a Quote is not new and has the status of approved then dont allow users to edit the fields. The problem is that I want every one to be able to edit a field called IID__c regardless of status. I am not sure at this point how with my current conditions. Below is my code.

```
AND( 
$User.ProfileId != '00eU0000000ZMaV', 
$User.ProfileId != '00e0B000000eNK5', 
$User.ProfileId != '00eU0000000mLpf', 
!ISNEW(), 
TEXT(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Status__c) != 'Draft', 
TEXT(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Status__c) != 'Rejected', 
!SBQQ__Quote__r.In_Apex_Context__c, 
OR( 
ISCHANGED(SBQQ__Discount__c), 
ISCHANGED(SBQQ__AdditionalDiscountAmount__c), 
) 
)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that once you would add an exception when `IID__c` is changed, everyone would be able to bypass this validation and modify any other field(s) (unless you would also restrict specific field(s) modification(s)), once they also modified `IID__c`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make it to where only the 1 field is allowed to be changed:

```
NOT(ISCHANGED(IID__c))
```

Add that into your formula instead of your `OR` and it will fire the rule if any field other than IID__c is changed. This is more efficient than trying to block at all fields except for the 1 you want edited.

Also, you should probably not use hard-coded ids. While it's probably mostly ok with profile since those Ids are fairly constant, it's just a best practice to use the name.

Lastly, what you're saying and what your code is saying are different. You say you want to stop all changes if status is accepted but your code says if the status is not draft or rejected. In this case you may have only the 3 status so it's probably the same thing, but if you added a 4th your rule would stop working. You want to make sure to do `status = accepted`

Something like this should work for a single field:

```
AND( 
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator', 
    $Profile.Name != 'Profile 2', 
    $Profile.Name != 'Profile 3', 
    !ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Status__c, 'Accepted')), 
    !SBQQ__Quote__r.In_Apex_Context__c, 
    NOT(ISCHANGED(IID__c))
)
```

### Multiple fields

This **should** work for allowing only the specified fields to be changed if you need more than 1 field in your logic.

```
AND( 
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator', 
    $Profile.Name != 'Profile 2', 
    $Profile.Name != 'Profile 3', 
    !ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Status__c, 'Accepted')), 
    !SBQQ__Quote__r.In_Apex_Context__c, 
    NOT(OR(
        ISCHANGED(IID__c),
        ISCHANGED(Number__c)
    ))
)
```

Comment: What if I needed another field that is allowed to be changed such as Number__c?

Comment: just add it right under the other one using the same syntax. Updated my answer

Comment: I thought so but that didnt work. I think it is because within the AND statement they would both have to change

Comment: @Brooke Try the new update, if any one of those changes `OR` will return true and it'll be negated (allowed) but if none of them change `OR` will be false and negated (true)

Comment: Nope didnt work still got the validation when changing the value in either one

Comment: I just created a rule simmilar to yours in my test org and tested all of the possible combinations and the method I have above does work. Chances are there is something else in your rule that is firing.